# make new repository in git hub

Tags: github, repository, remote-access

I have my project on GitHub at some location, 
`https:github.com/vidurasilva/loging_Form.git`

I used the commands one by one and there has errors also,

> C:\wamp\www\PhpProject>git remote add origin https:github.com/vidurasilva/Register_For_New.git
>   fatal: remote origin already exists.
>
> C:\wamp\www\PhpProject>git push -u origin master
>   fatal: unable to access 'https:github.com/vidurasilva/loging_Form.git/': Couldn't resolve host 'github.com'
>
> C:\wamp\www\PhpProject>git remote set-url origin git@github.com:vidurasilva/Register_Form_New.git
>
> C:\wamp\www\PhpProject>git push -u origin --all
>   ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

> C:\wamp\www\PhpProject>git clone https:github.com/vidurasilva/Register_Form_New.git

Cloning into `Register_Form_New`...
fatal: unable to access `https:github.com/vidurasilva/Register_Form_New.git/`: Couldn't resolve host `github.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add https://github.com/vidurasilva/Register_Form_New.git
git push origin master
```

Further assistance is available in [this article from GitHub support](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).

Comment: @K.V.C.Silva, please don't ever just say something "doesn't work" or "gives errors". Those error messages are _important_. You need to tell us exactly what they _say_. Otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

First fix this

```
git remote add origin https:github.com/vidurasilva/Register_For_New.git
```

with this

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/vidurasilva/Register_For_New.git
```

Then fix this

```
git clone https:github.com/vidurasilva/Register_Form_New.git
```

with this

```
git clone https://github.com/vidurasilva/Register_Form_New.git
```